# The target assembly contains no service types. You may need to adjust the Code Access Security policy of this assembly

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a small WCF solution with 2 methods but am getting this error when I build it.

If I leave the message without dismissing it, I get

```
WCF Service Host cannot find any service metadata. This may cause the client application to run improperly. Please check if metadata is enabled.
```

I'm pretty sure my config is wrong, probably the defined endpoint does not match the namespace but I'm not sure what to set where.

The namespace of the Contracts class is `JOB_1_0_Service.Contracts` with 2 methods.
In the `APP.Config` of this project is the following:

```xml
<endpoint address="/Address1" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="JOB_1_0_Service.Contracts.IService">
```

The contract methods are defined as:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    GetNearbyJobsResponse GetNearbyJobs(GetNearbyJobsRequest request);

    [OperationContract]
    GetChildJobsResponse GetChildJobs(GetChildJobsRequest request);
}
```

The namespace of the implementation class is `JOB_1_0_Service.Implementation` again with 2 methods:

```
GetNearbyJobsResponse IService.GetNearbyJobs(GetNearbyJobsRequest request)
{
    ...
}
```

and

```
GetChildJobsResponse IService.GetChildJobs(GetChildJobsRequest request)
{
    ...
}
```

What should I put in which config file - if indeed this is the problem?

[UPDATE]

Ok, so just to re-iterate:
I have 2 projects in 1 solution. 1 project contains the contracts and the other has the implementation code.

This also means there are 2 config files. So far I don't know which one needs modding in what way.

So, which is the one to modify, or do I need to modify both? I assume the implementation project is the one for the WCF config.

I'm now in the situation where, when I build it says I have no metadata exposed, and yet it also tries (and fails) to expose a contract as an endpoint!

[/UPDATE]

Comment: Ok it's working now, except I also get "The contract 'IMetaDataExchange' in client configuration does not match the name in service contract, or there is no valid method in this service"

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error becuase I had mistakenly commented out the [ServiceContract] attibute. Once I uncommented the [ServiceContract] attribute it all worked okay.

I hope this help others who face the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

Add the `<serviceMetadata/>` element to the service behavior for metadata

```
<configuration>
 <system.serviceModel>
  <services>
   <service name="WCFTest.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="Simplebehavior">
    <host>
     <baseAddresses>
      <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000/WCFTest/"/>
     </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint
     address=""
     binding="basicHttpBinding"
     contract="WCFTest.IService1"/>
    <endpoint
     address="mex"
     binding="mexHttpBinding"
     contract="IMetadataExchange" />
   </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
   <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="Simplebehavior">
     <serviceMetadata/>
     <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
   </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
 </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

---

Add below endpoint to exchange metadata

```
<endpoint
          address="mex"
          binding="mexHttpBinding"
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
```

Aslo check this for detail : [Random Error Message: WCF Service Host cannot find any service metadata](http://www.toplinestrategies.com/dotneters/random-error-message/random-error-message-wcf-service-host-cannot-find-any-service-metadata/?lang=en)

Comment: I think this is on the right track. So which config file needs the endpoint set to the namespace and class of the implementation code; the contracts or the implementation?

Comment: It doesn't say! In the example the contract and implementation are in the same project.

Comment: @bukko-ok... just include this in you webservice config file

Comment: Ok it's working now, except I also get "The contract 'IMetaDataExchange' in client configuration does not match the name in service contract, or there is no valid method in this service"

Comment: @bukko - i updated my answer with all change just match this config with the config in your file

Comment: @Parany thanks I updated my config. The only thing missing was the `behaviorConfiguration="Simplebehavior"` in the `<Service />` element. However the problem is still the same.

Comment: My config file matches the one on that page, apart from the namespaces.

Comment: Because it's a poor answer. You don't explain what the problem could be, just "try this" and "check this" even though the site does not address the problem at all. It looks like you are just guessing, hoping to get lucky. I was hoping for an informed answer. I know how to use Google! If you don't know, please say so!

Answer (score 1):

I had this error, and it turned out that I had the wrong project as the startup project: it was the first time I ever saw that error because of that, but oh well.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran across this. In my case, I had three assemblies: one for the service, one for the client, and one class library shared by the first two. The shared assembly project had an app.config file automatically created by VS. Removing that file fixed the problem.